How were lead sheets made in the Graeco-Roman world?
How did people make lead sheets in the Graeco-Roman world? Especially for the usage in curses.

This category is exemplarily represented by the so-called curse tablets (Gk. κατάδεσμος‎, Lat. defixio), thin lead sheets inscribed with maledictions intended to influence the actions or welfare of persons (or animals).
Versnel, H.  (2016, March 07). curses. Oxford Classical Dictionary. Retrieved 21 Nov. 2024.



afterwards folding sheets of lead began to be employed for official muniments,
Pliny the Elder, Natural History LCL 370: 140-141

How did they extract it from the earth (smelting?) and how did they craft it into such thin and foldable sheets?
Wikipedia is insufficient because, as far as I can tell, it does not discuss the topic.

The other answers have covered the production process from ore, known as smelting. It isn't quite as simple as the other answers seem to show, you do first need to crush the mineral galena, then smelt and then roasted to remove the sulphur component of lead. Galena is largely lead sulphide (PbS), so needs to be oxidized to the oxide (PbO) and then finally converted into lead itself. This purification system involves heating the lead in the presence of air for the first step, and then heating in the presence of charcoal to remove the oxygen in the oxide. Some of this is detailed in  Chapters 47-53, Book XXXIV of Pliny the Elder1.
However, the production of lead sheets is very simple and is a method that has been used for thousands of years, including by the Romans. This involves generating a flat surface using sand inside a tray and then simply pouring liquid lead over the surface. Some sand will adhere to the lead on the sand side leading to a rough texture, but you can easily get a sheet of a few millimetres in thickness or less with one smooth side and is easily produced in bulk. Vitruvius mentions sheets like these being used for the plumbing of Roman water supply in Book 8, Chapter 62, where they were rolled/bent around a form to shape into tubes, then soldered and/or rolled at the join to seal. From images of the cross-section, such as the ones in Crapper et al., 20223 (PDF), the sheets used in pipes appear to be several millimetres in thickness, not really what you want for reading/writing on.
As others have mentioned, lead is also extremely malleable, so easily beaten into sheets if needed. This would be a slow method of producing the necessary amounts of sheets, but could suit if enough people were working at it or the needed area was small.
However, looking at the literature around this topic, in particular the works of R.S.O. Tomlin on the various curse tablets, they were made by either cutting from a larger sheet of lead, be it freshly cast or re-purposed (e.g. left over from a pipe), or made by hammering out a small lump of the metal.
More details on the manufacture and use of curse tablets can be found in: Roger Tomlin, "The Curse Tablets" (suggested abbreviation: Tab. Sulis). Chapter 4 in B. Cunliffe (ED.)4, The Temple of Sulis Minerva at Bath, II: Finds From the Sacred Spring (Oxford University Committee for Archaeology, monograph 16, 1988. They describe the process (Abridged text sourced from Roman Inscriptions of Britain):

It was quite easy to make a tablet. The alloy melted at a low temperature, if need be in a pot or iron ladle over a domestic fire. To make a sheet, it could be poured over a flat surface: tablets sometimes exhibit ‘cold shuts’, small natural holes where the alloy failed to spread before it set. A good example can be seen in the corner of 46 (Pl. XXI). The only problem was that the surface tension of the liquid was too great for it to form a metal sheet thin enough to be conveniently inscribed and folded. (95 and 96 (Pl. XXVIIIa) are almost unique in being ‘blobs’ which were allowed to set and were then inscribed without further preparation.) There were two solutions to the problem, the Romans not using rollers to make lead sheet. The simpler solution was to hammer the metal after it had set: 54 is a good example, the hammering having caused the metal to spread out in a scalloped outline (Pl. XXVIa). It is often difficult to tell whether a thick tablet (0.8 mm or more) has been hammered or not, but 5, 8, 39, 53 and 58 probably have been. Hammering was certainly used to flatten two ‘late’ tablets with sophisticated texts, 65 and 97, so it is not an index of unsophistication, but it is less common than the other solution. This was to put the molten alloy under pressure, so that it set in a thin sheet. How this was done is not clear, but possibly the molten alloy was poured onto a smooth flat stone surface, and another smooth flat stone was lowered upon it. Tablets with uncut edges preserve evidence of the casting process. Sometimes the edge is sinuous or irregular, retaining the curving outline left by the spreading liquid as it cooled and set, with a bullnose cross-section due to the meniscus. Some tablets are entirely irregular, having been hammered or pressed from a pool of molten alloy; a few have been trimmed into irregular polygons, like the pentagons 5, 16 and 37; but a rectangle was evidently the preferred shape (3, 4, 6 and 15 are exceptional in being squares), and this was achieved in two ways. Usually the rectangle was cut or trimmed from a larger sheet, one or two sides sometimes preserving its original edge. This was done with a knife, sometimes in a series of short strokes, some of which might fail to sever the metal; there seems to have been no attempt at precision, by using a ruler for instance, or cutting right-angle corners. Even the blank tablet 117, which is exceptionally neat, was not cut with the aid of a ruler; and 2, which came from the same sheet, is very rounded in outline. Another blank tablet, 119, is also evidence of a sheet being cut up: three sides have been cut by a knife, the fourth preserves the irregular edge of the original.
The other way of achieving a rectangle is more interesting. The edge of some tablets, mostly fragments, has a flanged cross-section, either single (‘L’ profile) or double (‘T’ profile) (Pl. XXI). The edge runs more or less straight, the molten alloy evidently pressing against some obstruction as it set under pressure, no doubt the edge of a mould. A single flange suggests that the liquid forced its way upward, into the space between the side of the mould and its lid. A double flange suggests that it could also force its way downward, either because the mould was a wooden box whose bottom did not meet the sides perfectly, or because it was hollowed from stone and the sides had been chiselled a little too deep. Stone moulds were used for casting pewter plates and other vessels, so simple stone moulds may have been used for tablets too. Unfortunately these tablets, being quite thin, were fragile and only two survive reasonably complete, 10 and 44. Three cast edges survive of 79, but otherwise it is not clear from the single flanged edges which survive of fragments, or the occasional corner like that of 35, that the original tablet was cast in one piece. It can be seen that 10, 44 and 79 are all of different sizes, and that their sides are not straight. They clearly came from different moulds.

However, it should be noted that many of the curse tablets found at Bath (most of the known Roman ones are from Bath and Uley in Britain) weren't actually lead, most of them were pewter (an alloy of various metals and tin, in this case lead and tin), which was cheaper and more readily available than lead. Not that this makes much difference to the method of preparation, but pewter has a notably lower melting point (<230 C/446 F) than lead (327 C/621 F), and is even softer to work.
Refs:

The Natural History. Pliny the Elder. John Bostock, M.D., F.R.S. H.T. Riley, Esq., B.A. London. Taylor and Francis, Red Lion Court, Fleet Street. 1855. http://data.perseus.org/citations/urn:cts:latinLit:phi0978.phi001.perseus-eng1:34.47

Vitruvius: The Ten Books on Architecture. Vitruvius. Morris Hicky Morgan. Cambridge: Harvard University Press. London: Humphrey Milford. Oxford University Press. 1914. http://data.perseus.org/citations/urn:cts:latinLit:phi1056.phi001.perseus-eng1:8.6

Crapper, M., Motta, D., Sinclair, C., Cole, D., Monteleone, M., Cosheril, A., … Parkin, A. (2022). The hydraulic characteristics of Roman lead water pipes: An experimental investigation. The International Journal for the History of Engineering & Technology, 91(2), 119–134. https://doi.org/10.1080/17581206.2022.2054395

Tabellae Sulis: Roman inscribed tablets of tin and lead from the sacred spring at Bath by R.S.O. Tomlin, in Cunliffe, B. (ed.), The Temple of Sulis Minerva at Bath: Volume II, The Finds from the Sacred Spring (1988), published by Oxford University Committe for Archaeology.



Does Vitruvius specify the production of sheets by pouring molten lead? The other answers here talk about lead's malleability. Malleable ("capable of being shaped by hammering or rolling", from Latin "malleus" hammer) very literally suggests that sheets could be produced by hammering solid lead.

@SteveJessop I'm well aware of the meaning of malleable - I even used it in my answer. Vitruvius (8.6 para 4) says this: But if the water is to be conducted in lead pipes, first build a reservoir at the source... The pipes should be cast in lengths of at least ten feet Note the word cast in the last sentence - this implies casting, which is what the poured method is.

@SteveJessop In addition, casting in lengths of 10 feet is much much easier and faster than hammering them into this size; especially with the low melting point of lead.

Gotcha, thanks. I lazily searched for "roll" and missed that it said the original plates are "cast".

"this implies casting, which is what the poured method is": this implies casting was used tu make 10-foot long tubes.  It doesn't imply that they would have used the same method to make sheets, which have very different properties from pipes.

@phoog The rest of the quote is: The pipes should be cast in lengths of at least ten feet. If they are hundreds, they should weigh 1200 pounds each length; if eighties, 960 pounds; if fifties, 600 pounds; forties, 480 pounds; thirties, 360 pounds; twenties, 240 pounds; fifteens, 180 pounds; tens, 120 pounds; eights, 100 pounds; fives, 60 pounds. The pipes get the names of their sizes from the width of the plates, taken in digits, before they are rolled into tubes. Thus, when a pipe is made from a plate fifty digits in width, it will be called a “fifty,” and so on with the rest....cont

@phoog cont... Note the last two sentences in the quote. They were not cast as pipes, rather as sheets and then rolled into tubes and sealed by folding the lead over on itself and soldering. More details in PDF here.

Ok, but the thickness of a sheet that will be rolled into a pipe is probably significantly different from the thickness of a sheet that will be written on and folded.

@phoog For sure - see amended answer; looks like poured and then hammered or put under pressure (we do it with roller mills today) possibly by lowering a block of stone onto the cooling metal.

I also find it important to note explicitly that "rolling" has two fairly distinct meanings here; the modern definition of malleability that mentions "hammering or rolling" is almost certainly referring to the roller mills that you mention (a more efficient means of squishing metal into a sheet than hammering), whereas the "rolling" in the manufacture of a pipe from a rectangular sheet is bending it (presumably around a pole or other cylindrical form).  The success of this sort of rolling probably depends on both malleability and ductility, since it would put the outer surface under tension.

@phoog Good point, I'll edit the answer to make that more clear.

I also note that Ronald Hutton describes texts that urge the use of pipes from the water system, to get lead, and describes several possible motives for doing so, from the antisocial nature of the act to the cold nature of the water affecting the magic.

Lead ores are not as abundant as e.g. iron ores, but far from being rare. Galena, for example, is not only the main lead ore, but also one of the major sources of silver (making lead basically a byproduct of mining Galena for its silver content). Being very dense, lead ore can be separated from waste rock easily in a process called benefication.
Lead melts at as little as 327°C, so smelting it from the ore could be done over a simple wood fire, making lead an easily obtainable metal.
Once you have purified the lead, it can be worked easily; it shares many characteristics with other malleable metals like copper and gold, and isn't brittle at all.

Lead mining and refining is surprisingly easy. The only tough part is that it usually kills the workers in the process...

Lead is soft enough to be worked with common tools, and even  soft enough to be bent by hand.

Lead is a very soft metal with a Mohs hardness of 1.5; it can be scratched with a fingernail.29 It is quite malleable and somewhat ductile Anderson Wikipedia:Lead


Since lead is easily extracted from its ores, prehistoric people in the Near East were aware of it. Galena is a principal ore of lead which often bears silver. Interest in silver helped initiate widespread extraction and use of lead in ancient Rome. Wikipedia:Lead

Lead is not found in blocks, but is smelted from ores.

Metallic lead beads dating back to 7000–6500 BC have been found in Asia Minor and may represent the first example of metal smelting.[126] Ibid

Smelting of lead has been known from prehistoric times.
@justcal points to an article on Mining in Roman Britain that may help.
I'm not sure that I understand the question. Is there some reason why people wouldn't have been able to work lead into sheets?  I suspect that the question is founded on an unstated/unshared assumption about lead in the natural world.  Because I don't understand the question, I cannot provide a better answer. Recommend additional preliminary research.

Its fairly brittle (from my understanding). Likewise, I assume it was difficult to find.
My curiousity is how they were able to extract it from the earth (I assume it may have been removed in large blocks) as well as how it was crafted into such thin and foldable sheets for transport.

That information should be in the question. The second quote above answers - smelting of lead was done from 6500BCE.  Are you asking how they smelted? I'm having trouble answering the question because so little of the question is on the page.

@user2231142 I don't think they would have had much luck finding big blocks of lead in the ground - they would have mined lead ores and then smelted them.

@SPavel I think that makes more sense. I am not certain how they would have gotten the lead into such a thin sheet though.

Lead is quite easy to beat into thin sheets. It is an fcc metal, so is ductile.

A wiki article on Mining in Roman Britain goes into lead smelting and extraction from galena.

Molten lead could easily be poured onto a flat surface to solidify, then hammered thinner if required and cut into squares.

I'm not sure where you developed the impression that lead was brittle. If you've ever held lead you can bend it with the strength in your hands.

@JonCuster lead has relatively poor ductility but is highly malleable.  MCW this is perhaps the origin of the understanding that lead is brittle.

Nope, I' was quoting OP
